# How to power multiple pistons facing up?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

So, I'd like to know how to power a lot of pistons what are facing up.

[image: Here's an example.]

I want to know how to power these. I've also tried to use redstone under the pistons for an easier way but that doesn't work either. I want to power them with redstone dust, and a button, so it's toggleable. But I know redstone doesn't work that way.

[image: Another example with powered redstone underneath]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a bit of a hassle, but I normally use something like this:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I do know how redstone works tho. I just needed an alternative way. ;)

Comment: I'm writing from 5 years in the future. It's the year 2021, and Minecraft has advanced to version 1.17. My robot friend and I are wondering if this is *still* the best way to activate multiple pistons.

Comment: @EJMak Might be able to use slime/honey blocks now, depending on the goal, so that one piston can raise a bunch of blocks at once.

Answer (score 0):

If this was in creative mode with command blocks enabled, you could use the /fill command to fill the spaces underneath the pistons with either torches or redstone blocks.